# How much is the data energy loss in PCA?

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

Recently in a slide in about `PCA` (Principal Component Analysis) I saw a question: "How much is the data energy loss in `PCA`?" Then in the next slide I saw somethings that do not understand relation of last steps to the `PCA` and energy. Here you can see part of slide that tries to show an example:

[image]

Steps are:

1. `X` as input
2. normalize `X` (as `Z`)
3. compute covariance matrix of `Z` as `R`
4. eigenvalues of `R` in descending order as $\lambda$ and their corresponding vectors as `V`.
5. $S = V\lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $\lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is element-wise operation.
6. discard third column of `S` and sore it as `S`
7. calculate diagonal elements of $S S^{T}$ as `var` columnar matrix
8. `1 - var(2,1)` is the amount of energy loss of `PCA`. Here it is `1 - 0.8420`.

This is an `Octave` code that you can follow to get the same results:

```
X=[
7 4 3;4 1 8;6 3 5;8 6 1;8 5 7;
7 2 9;5 3 3;9 5 8;7 4 5;8 2 2];

rows=size(X)(1);
XMean = repmat(mean(X),rows,1);
XStd = repmat(std(X),rows,1);
X_normalized = (X - XMean)./(XStd);

Cov_mat=cov(X_normalized);

[V,lambda] = eigs(Cov_mat) %descending order
S = V * lambda^(0.5);
S1 = S(:,1:2);
var = diag(S1*S1')
```

Here are what I do not understand:

- What is the definition of `energy loss` of PCA? The only thing I could find about `PCA` and `energy` is `cumulative energy content for each eigenvector` in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). But it is not relative to the steps that here are described.
- Why did we keep only first two columns of `S`?
- Why `1 - var(2,1)` is the amount of energy loss of `PCA`? Does `2` in `1 - var(2,1)`
  is relative to the first *two* columns?
- Is `1 - var(2,1)` is the amount of energy loss of `PCA` by using two eigenvectors relative to the two eigenvectors with largest magnitude?
- If we want to calculate energy loss for only using eigenvector that is relative to the largest eigenvalue, do we have to calculate $[S(1,1) S(1,2) S(1,3)]^T [S(1,1) S(1,2) S(1,3)]$ as `var` and `1 - var(1,1)` is the amount of energy loss?

Comment: Something is missing.  Where does $Z$ come from, is it also an input ?

Comment: @HosamHAJEER $Z$ is the result of normalization of $X$. In `Octave` code, the variable `X_norm` stores it.

Comment: How do you normalize $X$ ?

Comment: @HosamHAJEER `XMean = repmat(mean(X),rows,1);
XStd = repmat(std(X),rows,1);
X_norm = (X - XMean)./(XStd);`

Comment: Please add  new information in comments as an edit to the post! We want posts to be self-contained, and information in comments will be overlooked by many ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen What I added as comment in response to `@Hosam HAJEER ` are also clear in the question. I only repeated those.